Creating a Bayes net with independence constraints
Create a Bayes net with exactly four states {A,B,C,D}, that follows all of the independence constraints below:
(a) A ⊥ B
(b) A $\not \perp$ D|B
(c) A ⊥ D|C
(d) A $\not \perp$ C
(e) B $\not \perp$ C
(f) A $\not \perp$ B|D
(g) B ⊥ D|A,C
How would I go about attempting this question? The answer seems so simple for a network with so many constraints. Is there an algorithm / method I can use? Or can someone provide a step by step explanation please?
I'm also confused as to how a simple constraint such as A ⊥ D|C could be represented as in a Bayes net?
Solution:

